# How do you make an HUD for a Cardboard game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, hud

Currently there is no documentation whatsoever on how to make a "visor" HUD on Unity for a Cardboard game. Screen Space - Overlay does not work as rendering mode as many people have already said. Does anyone know of a workaround/method for making it using World Space rendering?

Comment: Is moving the gui in front of the (world) camera an option? Childing the camera is another way, but I think it's a popular opinion that people respond better to VR menus if they can look around while seeing them. (You could have the UI gradually move towards the look direction, as a compromise.)

Answer (score 0):

You must create your HUD in a World Space canvas, put it in front of the camera and attach it to the Head object of the Cardboard SDK. That way it will be always visible in front of the player.